# nuget update-package sees new package, but doesn't update

Tags: nuget

I needed to add some files to an existing package. 
I used nuget package explorer to do this with the drag+drop method. I then incremented the version number from 1.1.6 to 1.1.7 and saved it.

In VS, update-package shows the new version but doesn't actually update it:

```
PM> update-package myPackage
Updating 'myPackage' from version '1.1.6' to '1.1.7' in project 'myProject'.
No updates available for 'myPackage' in project 'myProject'.
```

The package manager console also "sees" the update, but clicking the Update button does nothing. I emptied the package cache, which also didn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it turns out this package was just a set of arbitrary files with no direct references in the solution. 
Have switched to using the "Content" folder which now does as I would expect...